# Clarification on the Meaning of Pulse Amplitude in Qiskit Pulse

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

I'm unclear about the meaning of the pulse amplitude mentioned in the IBM Quantum's [Qiskit Pulse documentation](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/pulse). Does the pulse amplitude here refer to the physical amplitude (intensity) of the microwaves used in quantum computing? Or does it indicate the strength of the coupling between a transmon qubit and microwaves, as described in the [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/transmon-physics.html)?

If the pulse amplitude refers to the physical amplitude of the microwaves, what unit is associated with a specification like `drive_amp=0.05` in the [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html)? How does this amplitude value affect the manipulation of qubits?